# Ubuntu fails to complete package install using Snap

Tags: software-center, snap, spotify

When I try to install an application I can not and it tells me:

`Cannot install "spotify": snap "spotify" has "install-snap" change in progress.`

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question in English? Most of us won't be able to help you otherwise

Comment: When I try to install an application I can not and it tells me Cannot install ''spotify'': snap ''spotify'' has ''install-snap'' change in progress.

Answer (score 29):

The snap installed is trying to install your package (Spotify), but for some reason has failed. Please find the Change ID for the failed install with the command

```
snap changes
```

In the list which follows, you will find one line which leads off with a number, and ends with `Install "spotify" snap`.

Halt the failed install with the number found (let's pretend it is ***123***)

(please replace 123 with the number you find).

```
sudo snap abort 123
```

If the command executes successfully, then you will then be able to retry installation. Should reinstallation fail, please reboot your system and retry.

If other Snap packages are also hung up, use the

```
sudo snap abort nnn
```

command (where ***nnn*** is the number from the list generated by `snap changes`) to clear them as well.

Comment: I've tried it and I have this problem with all the applications I want to download

Comment: If other Snap packages are also hung up, use the `sudo snap abort nnn` 
command (where nnn is the number from the list generated by snap changes) to clear them as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with snap. Whenever the application installation from snap is interrupted, the service goes down. Execute the command `sudo systemctl restart snapd.service` and then try to install the software using `snap install <application_name>`

Answer (score 0):

After aborting, install the snap from terminal.
`sudo snap install <snap_name>`
Replace  with "spotify" to install spotify.
You can find snap name by running a search:
`snap search "query"`
Installing from terminal doesn't cause problems like software-center.