# snaps fail to install

Tags: snap

I do not know when this started, but my snap packages were all out of date. It turns out that `snapd` is unable to update. Installing new snaps is the same result.

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
error: cannot install "hello-world": cannot query the store for updates: got unexpected HTTP status
       code 408 via POST to "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh"
```

I have searched for various solutions but none of them worked. Indeed I have tried so many things I may have forgotten some of them.

- The server pings no problem.
- An `mrt` traceroute shows no packet loss.
- Disabling IPv6 makes no difference.
- `curl -s https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh` fails because it expects a POST request.

Basically, there's nothing wrong with the connection.

`snap debug connectivity` reports failure.

The usual restarts and reboots did nothing, as expected.

I [tried](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564322/45386) `snap download node` to manually install NodeJS, and the **download worked fine**, but after installing and attempting to run `node` I keep getting an exec error: `not found`. The binary exists in the path so... I gave up on that idea.

Eventually I bit the bullet and decided to purge `snapd`, remove and reinstall made no difference.

This was particularly difficult as I had to force unmount every Snap mount, and remove BTRFS snapshots created by the LXD snap - `apt purge snapd` on its own is not capable of doing this.

Once done, and I checked it was cleaned up, I installed again.

Success!

I began reinstalling all the snaps I wanted to use.

And then it stopped working again. Exactly the same error message, absolutely no solution.

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
error: cannot install "hello-world": cannot query the store for updates: got unexpected HTTP status
       code 408 via POST to "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh"
```

However, it was working for a few minutes!

```
$ snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
1    Done    today at 21:37 BST  today at 21:38 BST  Initialize system state
2    Done    today at 21:38 BST  today at 21:40 BST  Install "openra" snap
3    Doing   today at 21:38 BST  -                   Initialise device
4    Done    today at 21:41 BST  today at 21:42 BST  Install "anbox" snap from "edge" channel
5    Done    today at 21:44 BST  today at 21:44 BST  Install "node" snap from "18/stable" channel
6    Done    today at 21:45 BST  today at 21:46 BST  Install "code" snap
```

Now everything is failing in the same way.

```
May 22 22:04:01 ken snapd[10080]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "gnome-2048" revision unset
May 22 22:04:11 ken snapd[10080]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "hello-world" revision unset
May 22 22:07:09 ken snapd[10080]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "gnome-2048" revision unset
May 22 22:08:14 ken snapd[10080]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "guiscrcpy" revision unset
May 22 22:09:31 ken snapd[10080]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "vlc" revision unset
```

This time, however, the debug claims to connect no problem.

```
$ snap debug connectivity
Connectivity status:
 * PASS
```

I [tried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063675/ubuntu-fails-to-complete-package-install-using-snap) `sudo snap abort 3` but it just started again. I don't even know which package it is coming from, what is doing.... I'm at a loss. Snaps are a nightmare.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Code 408 errors tend to be transient for most users. If your is not, please report the problem to the snapd developers at https://forum.snapcraft.io so they can help troubleshoot it.

Comment: @user535733 If nobody can find a solution then I will head over to the forum. Thanks.

Comment: There appears to be no attempt whatsoever to help in that forum. On multiple fresh Bionic VMs it works every time. It would be nice if someone could point out how the damned thing works so I could (re)set it to a sensible state.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that there is no solution. It sometimes works, it sometimes doesn't. Server error and absolutely no way to get anybody to look into it.